# How to add a comment in a zip file with pyzipper?

Tags: python, zip

I am using Pyzipper to create a password protected zip file.
https://pypi.org/project/pyzipper/

But how is it possible to add a comment to the file in the zip, please?
I was looking inside pyzipper's `zipfile.py` and i see that it is supported:
`self.comment = b""               # Comment for each file`

I am trying like this, but it does not work:
I cannot figure it out. :(

```py
import pyzipper

def wgzipuser(wgfile,wgzippass):
    

    wgzipfilename = f"wgconfigs/{wgfile}.zip"
    
    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(wgzipfilename,
                            'w',
                            compression=pyzipper.ZIP_LZMA,
                            compresslevel=9,
                            ) as zf:
        zf.comment(bytes("Hello", encoding="utf-8"))
        zf.setpassword(bytes(wgzippass, encoding="utf-8"))
        zf.setencryption(pyzipper.WZ_AES, nbits=256)
        zf.write(f"wgconfigs/{wgfile}.conf")
        
        print(wgzipfilename)
        return wgzipfilename
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```py
   zf.comment(bytes("Hello", encoding="utf-8"))  
-> zf.comment = b"Hello"
```